# Angular Prod Build Leads to Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename 3rdpartylicenses.txt

Tags: angular, webpack

Basically what the title says. I can't figure out for the life of mine what the reason for that warning is. I had stumbled upon a similar issue on some other platform, but they suggest a solution that doesn't even appear to be available anymore from last year as seen here

[Angular 10 App shows Conflict Message on Build](https://fantashit.com/building-angular-10-app-shows-incomplete-warning-in-messages/)

Information seems otherwise incredibly scarce when it comes to this.

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "jquery", "ng9-odometer"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/my-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "my-app:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "my-app"
}
```

package.json

```
{
      "name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~11.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.9",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.8",
        "ng9-odometer": "^2.1.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.3",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1100.1",
        "@angular/cli": "^11.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~11.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
        "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
        "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
        "karma": "~5.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
        "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
        "protractor": "~7.0.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~6.1.0",
        "typescript": "~4.0.5"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find solution to this isssue?

Comment: @Perdikkas Sadly, I never did. I started a new project, same dependencies, no such issues.

Comment: That's indeed weird, thank anyway bud.

Answer (score 3):

Set **enableIvy** value to **true** in `tsconfig.json`.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the `.angular` folder and run `ng build` again.